# JSON href .append Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am pulling text from contentful.com via JSON. In this text I have a link (www.google.com)  that I want to make clickable. I regex the string with:

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,"<a    href='$1'>$1</a>"
```

It turns `www.google.com` into `<a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>`. When I then try to append this via a jquery function to a `ul` I get an `error:  Unexpected identifier`.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Edit:

```
$.getJSON( "http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/7la7mcq409gs/entries?\
access_token=",  function( data ) {

 $("#solutionsDiv ul").append('<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li- divider ui-bar-b ui-corner-top ui-first-child">Featured Solutions</li>');

 for (i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
 var replaced = data.items[i].fields.about;
 replaced = replaced.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
 replaced = replaced.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-  9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 

$("#solutionsDiv ul").append('<li data-theme="c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow"true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" class ="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-corner-bottom ui-li-last ui-li-static ui-last-child ui-btn-up-c"><div class = "ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c"><div class = "ui-btn-text"><a onClick = "newSolution(\'' +  data.items[i].fields.website + '\',\'' + replaced + '\',\'' + data.items[i].fields.slogan + '\',\'' + data.items[i].fields.productName + '\');" data-transition="slide" class="ui-link-inherit">' + data.items[i].fields.productName + '</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>');
```

Comment: Why use a RegEx for this? Why not just create the link?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? In my paragraph I have a link, but if I display it without te RegEx it is not clickable. I need to parse through a paragraph and make all the links clickable. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the actual code and not just the replace params?

Comment: Show the jQuery code...

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the appending? I get an error on the regex.

Comment: If I leave out the second replaced = the append works great. When I leave it in and try to append I get the error. So I would guess the error is coming from the regex. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the whole function, you're at least missing two `}`s. Also, there's some whitespace in your regex code which shouldn't be there (between `0-` and `9`).

Comment: It would be helpful if people would post regex questions in the format of given x, I get y, but expect z. Did you forget escaping your +'es?

Comment: Hi @Mithon. Given: "http://www.bing.com". I expect: <a href='http://www.bing.com'>http://www.bing.com</a>. I get this but still get an error.

Comment: @SeanRichardson -- I get that you have the text, just build the link, `var link = "<a href='" + text + "'>" + text + "</a>"` no need for RegEx

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you've copy-pasted some regex without writing it yourself, and thusly not understanding what it does. :)

In this particular case, I believe it was intended to take fully written out uri's only, and not short-form ones.

In this variation,

```
(\b((:?https?|ftp|file):\/\/)?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])
```

I've made the protocol prefix optional, so that it works on your bing.com example.